# Unable to access 'download' attribute in Html5 in MVC JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to access download attribute in a tag in HTML 5 which I wanted to access it in JavaSript Code. It is showing unknown attribute 'download'
Here is the tag that I am using to download.

```
<a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
```

This is my JS code.

```
var create = document.getElementById('btncreate'), 
    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox'); 
create.addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function () { 
        var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink'); 
        link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value); 
        link.style.display = 'block'; }, 
    false);
```

Comment: This is my JS code.

var create = document.getElementById('btncreate'),
            textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
        create.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
            link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
            link.style.display = 'block';
        }, false);

Comment: use [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30092184/edit) button instead of trying to post additional code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download attribute is [not supported in some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download), in those cases the download property on the element will be undefined.

In the cases of those browsers you need to use getAttribute to get the value

```js
var a = document.querySelector("a");
var log = document.querySelector("#log");
log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "Download property: "+a.download+"<br>"  );
log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "Download attribute: "+a.getAttribute("download") );
```

```html
<a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>

<div id="log"></div>
```